# Stat command problem in Python, how can I correct the error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command, stat

Good morning, I am doing a job at the university and they give me this command in order to search all the files of an address and find the ones that you have permission to execute for the group "others":

```
def permisosX(): 

    mypath = "/home/milax"
    from os import listdir
    from os.path import isfile, join
    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
    for f in onlyfiles:
      aux = os.stat(f).st_mode
      if ((aux & stat.S_IXOTH)):
        print(f)
```

It works fine when I run at the same address as the .py program, but if the program is saved and run at another address other than "mypath", an error appears. Why did this happen? How can I fix it to work anywhere regardless of where it's saved?

Thanks

Comment: Please paste the error into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `mypath` is not the current directory, then you need to include it in the call to `stat()`:

```
aux = os.stat(join(mypath, f)).st_mode
```

You will probably also want to include that in the print statement.

Answer (score 0):

@John Gordon is right.

What you were missing is the join in the `aux = os.stat(f).st_mode` line.

Another way to fix it and to display the absolute path would be to write

`onlyfiles = [join(mypath, f) for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]`

However I would suggest to rewrite the entire code in a more modern way by using `pathlib`

```
import stat
import pathlib

def permisosX(mypath):
    files = pathlib.Path(mypath).glob("*")
    onlyfiles = [f for f in files if f.is_file()]
    for f in onlyfiles:
      aux = f.stat().st_mode
      if ((aux & stat.S_IXOTH)):
        print(str(f))

permisosX(".")
permisosX("/home/milax")
```